# HTML/CSS Size Link to Image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a link with an image like this

```
<a href="http://test.com">
    <img src="image.png" />
</a>
```

It's showing up fine, but the clickable area of the link is larger than the image (a `50px` circle). I would like to only allow the area of the image to be clickable. I tried to do this with the following css, but to no avail:

```
a {
    max-width: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Changing the width and max-width seems to have no effect. What would be the best way to do this?

I'm trying to do this for the circular contact buttons on the bottom of [this site](http://matthewcooper.us).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a solution:

```
#contact a { display: inline-block; }
```

the `a` tag is taking the entire `width` of the parent tag as it's been rendering as a `block`, if you want force it to render only the content of it's child, you can use `inline-block`.

Comment: This almost works perfectly. The shape of the div is correct now; however, the clickable area still extends out to the square around the circle. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: I really don't think you can do much as your image is actually a square, the only way you could accomplish that, is using [image map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_map) ... personal opinion: I think that is just perfect and you should not worry about it!

Comment: Alright, I suppose I could achieve that functionality with some js on a circular div anyways. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Two things, the image on your website is not embedded into an anchor as you described.  And the link you provide is missing the `www.` possibly calling a page that cannot respond or does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Make the image as a background to that div shape ( circle ) , you can get circle by css3 radius .
The disadvantage of this is that the image will no longer be imbedded as an HTML img .
Then It will work just fine , i think

Answer (score 0):

You can give your link a class, such as .social-link, and apply the following code:

```
.social-link{
  max-width: 50px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```